# InDesign: Relinking broken library links breaks links for other users

Tags: adobe-indesign, asset-management, library

Working off of the same server we have an interesting problem. When one user creates a library on their machine and saves it to the shared server, all connect via the same macOSs path, then when another user loads the library from the server their links are broken and the media needs to be relinked.

My first thought was that the server is being mounted under slightly different paths on each users machine but, after inspection this is not the case. I made sure that they were connecting the exact same way and even checked the paths when they were being relinked to be sure.

There is obviously a path issue because once another user relinks an asset the original user now has broken links. Can someone please give me some advice on troubleshooting this problem further? Has anyone out there experienced similar problems?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this troubleshooting article? https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/creative-cloud-libraries-panel-doesn-t-load-in-desktop-products.html

Comment: Thanks for the idea but this is not the problem i am having.

Comment: Can you explain it a little better? It sounds like you are having to relink images after people edit them which is normal. Everyone is able to access the library still correct?

Comment: Yeah, so after some tests, it appears that users with version 13.0 are the ones who, after opening a library, have broken links. I am having everyone update their inDesign version now but it is very strange. Yes everyone can access the library on the server, I have made sure they are adding assets to the libraries From the server (a simple mistake)... I set up a test install on my own machine and i do not have the same problem... I'll update you all after I've had them all upgrade their installs.

Comment: Nope. The version was not the issue. It is so weird that it works fine on a few of our machines and not others...

Comment: this is not really a design question...